# Rabbitmq doesn't persistent a message in exchange if there is no subscriber?

Tags: rabbitmq, publish-subscribe

I have the following publisher and subscriber:

```
// publisher.js

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var ex = 'logs';
    var msg = process.argv.slice(2).join(' ') || 'Hello World!';

    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', {durable: true});
    ch.publish(ex, '', new Buffer(msg));
    console.log(" [x] Sent %s", msg);
  });

  setTimeout(function() { conn.close(); process.exit(0) }, 500);
});
```

```
//subscriber.js

var amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(err, conn) {
  conn.createChannel(function(err, ch) {
    var ex = 'logs';

    ch.assertExchange(ex, 'fanout', {durable: true});

    ch.assertQueue('', {exclusive: true}, function(err, q) {
      console.log(" [*] Waiting for messages in %s. To exit press CTRL+C", q.queue);
      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, ex, '');

      ch.consume(q.queue, function(msg) {
        if(msg.content) {
          console.log(" [x] %s", msg.content.toString());
        }
      }, {noAck: true});
    });
  });
});
```

If I run the publisher.js to publish two messages, and then run the subscriber.js, I would expect the subscriber to print two messages that I published in the past, but actually subscriber doesn't receive any messages.

How to let RabbitMQ persist the published messages that allow any subscriber to consume from the beginning or wherever they consumed last time?

Comment: Did you mean to publish in your subscriber code?

Comment: Sorry, i realized i pasted the wrong subscriber code. Now I've just updated.

Answer (score 1):

If RabbitMQ can't route a message to a queue, the message is dropped.

Since you run your publisher code prior to your subscriber code, there is no queue bound to your exchange and, thus, nowhere to route the message.

You need to either run your subscriber code before your publisher, or you have to have your publisher or some other process create and bind a named queue to your exchange. Then, your subscriber will use that queue.

Comment: Thank you @LukeBakken. For your first suggestion: I can't run my subscriber before my publisher, because I'd like to ensure even all my subscribers are down, my publisher can still publish messages which won't be dropped. For your second suggestion, can a queue be configured as "fanout" as well? I thought only exchange can be configured as "fanout". If a queue can't be "fanout", then I can't have multiple subscribers subscribing the same message like pubsub.

Comment: Something has to create and bind the queues to the fanout exchange - either you have to do it manually, or your publisher does, or your subscribers do, or all three. There is no harm in declaring the same queue multiple times. Note that you can't use exclusive queues for this scenario, either, because neither you nor your publisher code can create them. You must use well-known named queues if they must exist prior to your consumers.